# RedisSearch greater than datetime query does not work

Tags: c#, redis, redisjson

I try to query item from json storage which datetime property have to be greater than DateTime.UtcNow, here is the example:

```
var datetime = DateTime.UtcNow;
var obj = json.Get(key, path: $"$.event[?(@.Expires_At>=\"{datetime}\")]");
```

But it can`t find it.
Less than works and returns the data:

```
var obj2 = json.Get<T>(key, path: $"$.event[?(@.Starts_At<\"{datetime}\")]");
```

I`ve tried googling how redis handles comparing datetime fields, but there is no right example with greater than(also less than)

I`m expecting to find the object that has Expires_At field`s value greater than DateTime.UtcNow

Update:
The data in the json storage:

- Starts_At:"2023-06-24T18:54:07.682Z"
- Expires_At:"2023-06-29T18:54:07.682Z"

Comment: How have you stored the datetime in the JSON? Perhaps you could share the JSON you have saved.

Comment: @GuyRoyse Yes, datetime is stored in the json, shared in the desription update

Comment: I'm not a .NET guy. What is the value that `DateTime.UtcNow` returns? Is it returning the same ISO-8601 formatted string that you are storing in the JSON?